# Blue Green Deployment for particular MicroService

Tags: kubernetes, blue-green-deployment

I am using Kubernetes cluster for deploying our bunch of Microservices.I am able to manage Blue Green depoyment for all microservices at the same time like below[image]

My problem is that some times i want to deploy only App1 or App2 or both not all microservices.is this possible to manage this using Blue Green deployment?

Implemented Things:(want to deploy only App3 using blue green strategy)

if i am running BlueApp3 with blue deployment and GreenApp1 and GreenApp2 refirring BlueApp3. then i tested my whole application

[image]

once it will work fine i'll convert BlueApp3 to GreeApp3 like below[image]

1. is this strategy is fine?
2. if not then why?
3. do we need to deploy all bunch of MicorServices at a time to implement blue green deployment(it will cause unnecesaary deployment)
4. what are the pros and cons of Blue Green deployment strategy what i am following for one particular microservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest switching your deployment strategy from combined to per microservice completely. That includes the fact that you will no longer run all-blue or all-green deployment.

You can launch new deployment for given service, and when it is in place switch the selector under your kubernetes service from say `app: app2, flavor: green` to `app: app2, flavor: blue` and when considered as validated simply delete the green Deployment object.

The one setback from doing blue-green on k8s is that you don't really utilise potential provided by k8s deployments with their native support for RollingUpdates

Comment: can you elaborate more on setback you mentioned for blue-green deployment with k8s?

Comment: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/ gives you the ability to do a rolling update of a service simply by updating the deployment spec. With B-G approach you have to script most of that on your own

Comment: You can easily achieve the B-G approach described above for each microservice using [bg-kube](https://github.com/stphivos/bg-kube) using just the kubernetes manifests and optionally a `.env` file.